# Video Intent not saving video to desired location

Tags: android, android-intent

I have implemented a code to save the captured video to a custom location.

```
// Constants
final static int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED = 1;
String CAPTURE_TITLE="MyVideo.3gp";

// Specified the desired location here 
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM", CAPTURE_TITLE);
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file ); 



Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED);
```

Now On Activity result I m getting the default path only and not the desired path where i intent to save the video.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
          Uri capturedImageUri = data.getData();
          Toast.makeText(this, capturedImageUri .getPath(), TOAST.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
        }
    }
```

Now I dont know why it is not saving it to desired location similar thing I did try with Image capture and it worked.

Also I have added the desired permissions.

Any thoughts!!

Comment: can you give me  link where you find this example on Android Developer Site

Comment: see i don't think you can do that, but once recording done you can get the recorded path and can move the file werever you want.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html this is the link..@imran

Comment: @AdityaPratap : as i told you yesterday look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html again he is not passing Video Uri with intent and you are passing Video Uri with intent when Starting Camera. can you plz make me clear what you want?

Comment: @Imran:- Sir my motive is just to save the video that i captured to my desired loaction with my custom name   and the example shows that he is passing the Uri (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-video)  .  I did similarly for Image Capture and it was working fine   but not for video capture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this instead...

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)), CAPTURE_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM", CAPTURE_TITLE);
```

Change To:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/", CAPTURE_TITLE);
```

Comment: No Sir!! that would not be correct as the first parameter takes the folder name.  However I tired your change and it didn't worked.!!